# Importar modulos de nodejs a un html

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs

Intento importar el modulo fs/promise a un html pero no lo reconoce. Mi código es mas o menos así:

```
//file: add.js
import * as fs from 'fs/promises'

export let añadir = async (fileData, newUser) => {
    const getFile = await fs.readFile(fileData, 'utf-8');
}
```

```
//file: index.js
import { añadir } from './modules/add.js'
```

```
//file: index.html
<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
```

Me lanza el siguiente error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "fs/promises". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

En el package.json agregue la linea
`"type": "module",`

No se si estoy pasando algo por alto o simplemente estoy equivocado en todo

Comment: ¿Qué pretendes hacer con el módulo `fs/promises` en el navegador? Por motivos de seguridad, el navegador no te permite acceso al sistema de archivos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error te indica que las rutas relativas deben empezar por ./, ../, o /

Es decir, cambia el import de:

```js
import * as fs from 'fs/promises'
```

```js
import * as fs from './fs/promises'
```

De todas formas el código no te va a funcionar porque estás intentando importar un módulo interno de node para utilizarlo en el navegador y esto no es posible.

Lo que debes hacer en su lugar es crear un servidor en node (usa express por sencillez) que atienda las peticiones que el navegador le haga con fetch, abra el archivo con fs/promises y una vez que node accedió al archivo, debe responder al navegador con la información que precisas.

La lógica que debes implementar es algo del estilo de:

servidor/index.js

```js
import * as fs from 'fs/promises'
import app from express

// inicializa y configura express aquí

const leerFichero = (peticion, respuesta) => {
  // obten nombreFichero aquí:

  // lee contenido del fichero aquí usando fs/promise:

  // envia contenido del fichero al navegador:
  respuesta.send(miFichero);
}

app.get("leerFichero/:nombreFichero", leerFichero);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("API disponible en http://127.0.0.1:3000/"));
```

cliente/index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
...
<body>
<script src="../cliente/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

cliente/index.js

```js
const nombreFichero = prompt("Nombre del fichero a mostrar");

fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:3000/leerFichero/${nombreFichero}`)
.then( data => data.text() )
.then( fichero => console.log(`El fichero ${nombreFichero} contiene:\n${fichero}`) );
```